# VaDump not listing Memory Use of DLLs

Tags: wpf, memory, dll

I am trying to profile a large WPF application using VADump. I am most interested in the working set of DLLs. However, when I run VADump on my application using the command *vadump -sop [processID]*, there is no information displayed in this category. It has the headers but no DLLs are listed.

If I run VADump on a smaller app, I do get results. I am using the latest version of VADump. This is on Windows 7 x64, .Net 4.0, and Visual Studio 2010 Pro.

Questions I've looked at:

[Using VADump to track memory usage - OpenProcess Failed c0000034](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/955034/using-vadump-to-track-memory-usage-openprocess-failed-c0000034)

Any thoughts? I know VADump is an older tool.

Answer (score 1):

That mostly because DLLs don't own memory.  A process does.  Especially a managed one, the garbage collected heap is owned by an AppDomain and shared by all DLLs loaded into it.   There might be an unmanaged DLL that created its own heap, COM servers typically do.  But it's rare.

VADump isn't going to be any help diagnosing the gc heap either, use a .NET specific memory profiler.  The free CLR Profiler available from Microsoft for example.  It isn't worth the money you pay for it though.  There are a gazillion questions about profilers already, use the Search box.