# Most Accurate Way to Get Memory Usage for Silverlight Browser Application

Tags: c#, silverlight

Currently i'm tracking down a memory leak issue in a Silverlight 4 application.  I can watch the memory used by iexplorer.exe increase gradually using Task Manager.

However, I am looking for a way within the Silverlight code to tell how much memory the application is currently using within the IE Process.  I have tried GC.GetTotalMemory but it does not represent the actual memory usage by iexplorer.

I have developer tools for tracking down the memory leak itself, so i'm not looking for that but a method within my Silverlight code to get total IE memory usage, or at least a closer representation of what is actually being used by Silverlight instead of what the Garbage collector thinks is being used.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

GC allocated memory is good estimation of dynamic portion of memory used by SL application. Otherwise it is unclear what other types of memory usage you need.

If you need some other data consider using VaDump first ( http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/dd882521.aspx linked from [Using VADump to track memory usage - OpenProcess Failed c0000034](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/955034/using-vadump-to-track-memory-usage-openprocess-failed-c0000034)). When you figure out what portion/type of memory you are interested in it should be relatively easy to get this information (you may need to collect it with native calls, but likely all can be PInvoke'ed).

Update: I think all information you looking for is avaialble through performance counters - usage sample - http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.performancecounter.countername.aspx (but I'm don't think you can get it from SL).

Comment: So what I'm looking for is a combination of all the types of memory currently being used.  (What Windows Task Manager reports).  For instance in one snapshot I have 18.05MB and 3.168 MB between my Generation 2 and Large Object Heap but Unmanaged has 110.1 MB.  So I'm looking for a way to get the Unmanaged amount or total amount via managed code, if possible.

Answer (score 0):

Try the visual studio profiler

https://blogs.msdn.com/b/profiler/archive/2010/04/26/vs2010-silverlight-4-profiling.aspx

> "For .NET memory profiling, use “VSPerfClrEnv /samplegc” or “VSPerfClrEnv /samplegclife” in your step 1 to get either allocation profiling or allocation and lifetime profiling. "

Comment: That's a good article, but I'm looking for a way to tell memory usage from within managed code in the compiled Silverlight application.

Answer (score 0):

ANTS Profiler...

http://www.red-gate.com/products/dotnet-development/ants-memory-profiler/

Comment: While I have used this tool and think that it's amazing it doesn't meet what I need.  I need something that is compiled into my application so that my application can get an accurate memory usage reading.